# How does author-initiated peer review differ from double blind peer review?

Tags: publications, peer-review

Some journals ([example](https://riojournal.com/about#Unique-Features)) today ask the authors to initiate a peer review rather than initiating a blind peer review themselves.

Are these articles different in terms of quality and bias?
Are these articles accepted by experts/professors/scientists like regularly peer-reviewed articles?